# GmailApiQuickstart error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am just following steps from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java

I have downloaded the json file and followed all steps before. This line is throwing an IllegalArgumentException in GmailApiQuickstart.java (unchaged except json path). PAth is correct as in debug mode I can see json read correctly. As the tutorials are fairly new and are likely created for earlier versions, not sure if this is a bug introduced due to version update. The jar was updated fairly recently - 2 days before 
https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~google-api-services-gmail

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(SCOPE))
    .setAccessType("online")
    .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException     at
>   com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:80)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:195)
>     at GmailApiQuickstart.main(GmailApiQuickstart.java:42)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I have similar issue. I use latest version with maven

Comment: Did you guys get to the bottom of this? I'm having teh exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This quickstart was written using the latest version of the Google Api Java Client.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Are you using this version?